# HAML Rails nested partials not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have multiple views that are each tucked into a bunch of divs:

```
.row
  .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
        / Page heading goes here (eg. @form_heading)
      .panel-body
        = render 'form'
```

This is used for `show`, `new`, and `edit` across multiple models and displays as expected. `index` has a different layout. Because of that, I can't just add these divs to `application.html.haml`

It doesn't seem very DRY to have that in every `show`, `new`, and `edit` view, but, when I put it in a partial I get errors.

If I use:

```
# shared/_display_panel.html.haml
.row
  .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
      / Page heading goes here (eg. @form_heading)
      .panel-body

# _form.html.haml
= simple_form_for @job do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :summary
    = f.input :body
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, 'Save Job', class: 'btn-success'
```

as my partials and then try:

```
# new.html.haml
= render 'shared/display_panel'
= render 'form'
```

I, as expected, get the `form` rendered outside/under the `display_panel` divs.

If I try:

```
# new.html.haml
= render 'shared/display_panel'
  = render 'form'
```

Rails throws the following error:

```
/home/(me)/Projects/(current-project)/app/views/(my-model)/new.html.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^~~~~~
Extracted source (around line #4):
  2   = render 'form'
```

I get the same errors if I move `.panel-body` to the `_form` and try both methods.

How can I set this up to use partials with HAML and get it all to display the way expected?

### Edit:

Ideally, I would like to have a set of "style" partials that just set up the div/class structure for each view, regardless of their model or controller:

- one for `new`, `edit`, and `show`
- one for `index`

That would be something like the `_display_panel.html.haml` shown above.
I would also like to be able to render a form partial after that based on the model they are currently working with. I don't want to put all of the logic do determine model and method in the partial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`content_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for) to "assign" rendered output to specific content regions:

#### shared/_display_panel.html.haml

```
.row
  .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
      / Page heading goes here (eg. @form_heading)
      .panel-body
        = content_for(:panel_body)
```

#### _form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @job do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :summary
    = f.input :body
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, 'Save Job', class: 'btn-success'
```

#### new.html.haml

```
- content_for :display_panel do
  = render 'form'

= render 'shared/display_panel'
```

---

Even if you didn't know about `content_for`, the cleaner solution is to "push" the name of a partial into your view using a "locals" variable:

#### shared/_display_panel.html.haml

```
.row
  .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
      / Page heading goes here (eg. @form_heading)
      .panel-body
        = render partial_to_render
```

#### new.html.haml

```
= render 'shared/display_panel', partial_to_render: 'form'
# equivalent to
# render partial: 'shared/display_name', locals: { partial_to_render: 'form' }
```

Comment: I tried the first half of this and it failed. It didn't throw an error, just rendered a blank page using the `layouts/application.html.haml` defaults. However, after fighting with it for a bit, I came back here and saw your edit, and the second part works PERFECT! Thank you so much! 

If you don't mind, where can I learn more about this "cleaner solution"? I've not seen this in any of the tuts or books I've been through.

Comment: I did have to edit `partial_to_render: 'new'` to `partial_to_render: 'form'`, but, I knew what you meant, so, still immensely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that way, the `'shared/display_panel'` block is already closed when you render the `form` partial. Try to render the form partial inside the `display_panel`. You can use a conditional inside the view if you don't want to it to be shown in every view.

You can do it like this:

```
# shared/_display_panel.html.haml
.row
 .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2
  .panel.panel-default
   .panel-heading
    / Page heading goes here (eg. @form_heading)
   .panel-body
- if controller.controller_name == "your_controller_name" && controller.action_name == "new"
  = render 'form
```

Don't forget to indent render the added part to the point you want it to be nested

Comment: That would mean having a conditional rendered form in every view. Although that could work, it seems 'dirty'. There has to be some standard way to do this. This seems like it would be something that people would commonly run in to. I would think there is some 'clean' way to do it that we're overlooking.  Using your method, if I have 7 controllers and 21 views that all need this div tree, it seems I would need a pretty complicated logic in my view to get it to work right, and that doesn't seem to be the Rails way of doing things.

Comment: You are absolutely right on this. That was not what the what I meant though. I may not be getting it right at all. What I thought was that you want to nest the one partial inside the other but only show it when needed.  I mean the `display_panel` partial can be used in every controller -  model but I suppose you need another form for every single model! That fact itself force you to render a different form on each model. I may still no getting it right though :/

Comment: No worries. I appreciate the input either way. It helps me brainstorm a solution. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I did try nesting one partial inside the other in the process of trying to work out a solution, but, it throws the same error regardless of whether I render one partial inside the other or if I just nest them using HAML indentation.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You should absolutely not create and maintain a big `if/elsif/elsif/` tree way down inside some view, just to conditionally render content there.